# Generate all natural numbers that have 3 digits whose 3rd digit - 1st digit=2nd digit

Tags: c++

The problem's in the title.
If possible please give me exaplanations on what I did wrong and why correct solution is correct.

My attempt at solving it is in the code below... it was supposed get me all the 3 digit numbers then extract `digit1`, `digit2` and `digit3` from each number after which it should show the numbers that respect the `digit3-digit1==digit2`.
The program runs without errors but at the same time it doesn't really do anything.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Number,digit1,digit2,digit3,h;
    for (Number=100; Number<=999; Number++)
    {
        h=Number;
    }
    digit1=h/100;
    digit2=(h/10)%10;
    digit3=h%10;
    if (digit3-digit1==digit2)
        cout<<digit1<<digit2<<digit3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to stick most of the code into the loop instead of having it outside of the loop body.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Yeah it does work now. Can you please tell me what's the difference between sticking most of the code in the loop and placing it outside and also how to make each number show on different lines? I don't know how to do that for loops.

Comment: If it's outside the loop then it only works on the value `999`, because that is the last value that `h` is set to before the loop exits. To print a new line you have to do `cout << endl` or just place `<< endl` at the end of the print statement before the semicolon.

Comment: You could also generate only the desired numbers instead of searching for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that comes after the loop (other than `return 0`) has to go inside the loop. If it's outside the loop then it only works on the value 999, because that is the last value that `h` is set to before the loop exits. To print a new line you have to do `cout << endl` or just place `<< endl` at the end of the print statement before the semicolon.

A few optimizations can be made here. You don't need to loop through all 899 numbers. Given the constraints the the third digit has to be greater than or equal to the first digit, so you can just run a loop for the first digit, and nested loop for the third digit that starts from the first digit.

```c++
for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
  for (int c = a; c < 10; c++) {
    int b = c - a;
    cout << a << b << c << endl;
  }
}
```